# In trying to install flask and virtualenv in PYTHON, there are two errors. 1. UnicodeDecodeError:'ascii' codec. (with REDIRECTION ISSUE) 2. OSError

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, virtualenv

As I described on the headline, I'm trying to install flask in python. After finishing installing virtualenv, in creating a virtual environment, when I enter 'virturalenv venv', I got two errors !

**1. UnicodeDecodeError**

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc7 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I searched during a lot of time to find the solution, and I got a bunch of various solutions from other questions. And most of them is about encoding types such as 'cpc949', 'mbcs' and so on.

So I tried to replace 'ascii' to them(cpc949, mbcs or...), and I got a terrible error. The encoding type was redirected! Although I modified the encoding type in  'site.py' file, when I committed 'virtualenv venv' again at cmd in windows, the error shows again. After that, I checked site.py file again, the encoding type was redirected. It's odd.....

Any suggestions, comments or idea :) ?

**2. OSError**

```
OSError: Command C:\myproject\venv\Scripts\python.exe -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip failed with error code 2
```

with this, I have no idea at all. Who anybody has idea ??

.
**And here is the photos of the errors :**
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzJpcZZu99ZnMl9nQTFnS3VaSWM&authuser=0
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzJpcZZu99ZnOVh5RUtnSklTbDA&authuser=0
(because of my less reputation score)

Please help sir. Very thanks. Sincerely